# Compound/Composite key association with Sequelize

Tags: database, sequelize.js

Does anyone know how I can use compound keys to relate to a table using `Sequelize` and their built in relationships?

I have tried useing `primaryKey: true` and `unique:` with no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example , how you can define composite key in sequlize

```
sequelize.define('item_likes',{
    item_id:{
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        unique:"liked_user" // this will create composite key
    },
    user_id:{
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        unique:"liked_user" // this will create composite key
    },
    anonymously:{
        type : db.Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue : false,
        comment :  "( True : user wants to be anonymous )"
    }
}
```

All you need to do is use `unique:"liked_user"` , where `liked_user` is name of key , just for identification , and that should be same for the fields you want to make composite.

**Association :**

```
ItemLikes.belongsTo(Item,{foreignKey: 'item_id'});
Item.hasMany(ItemLikes,{foreignKey:'item_id'});

ItemLikes.belongsTo(User,{ foreignKey : 'user_id'});
User.hasMany(ItemLikes, { foreignKey: 'user_id'});
```

Comment: How do I add the associations?